# Recursively make directories: search for recursion

Tags: python

I have a list of directory names:

```py
dirnames = ["foo/bar", "foo/bar/mydir", "bar/mydir", "bar"]
```

I would like to (recursively) create all directories. What suffices is to recursively create the deepest directories only. In this case, it is sufficient to:

```py
os.makedirs("foo/bar/mydir")
os.makedirs("bar/mydir")
```

The question: How do reduce `dirnames` to have the deepest directories only?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: A simple for loop has O(n) complexity to create all directories. Shortening to only the deepest directories will actually cost you time (in the Big Oh sense) if the algorithm to do so is worse than O(n).

Comment: `sorted([(len(i.split('/')), i) for i in dirnames])[-2:]` will give top 2 deepest dirnames

Comment: @deadshot I did not think the question would have improved with my failed attempts. I started writing things that were way too complicated, and, it turns out in the wrong direction, see the nice answer below. In hindsight, the question maybe should have been shortened by leaving out the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While others have posted very useful iterative solutions, here is a way by which the full directories can be selected recursively:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def to_tree(d):
  t = defaultdict(list)
  for a, *b in d:
     t[a].append(b)
  return {a:None if not (k:=list(filter(None, b))) else to_tree(k) for a, b in t.items()}

def get_paths(d, c = []):
  for a, b in d.items():
     if b is None:
        yield '/'.join(c+[a])
     else:
        yield from get_paths(b, c + [a])


dirnames = ["foo/bar", "foo/bar/mydir", "bar/mydir", "bar"]
print(list(get_paths(to_tree([i.split('/') for i in dirnames]))))
```

Output:

```
['foo/bar/mydir', 'bar/mydir']
```

Comment: That is really great. The solution with the `defaultdict` is really smart I think!

Answer (score 1):

```
dirnames = ["foo/bar", "foo/bar/mydir", "bar/mydir", "bar","foo/bar/dir2"]
from itertools import groupby
import heapq
d=[sorted(list(g)) for (k,g) in groupby(sorted(dirnames), key= lambda x: x.split('/')[0])]
[max(elem) for elem in d]
```

or if you need the depth of 2

```
[heapq.nlargest(2, elem) for elem in d]
```

Using `groupby`  on parent directory. i.e `foo` or `bar`.If we use `max` we gonna get only `foo/bar/mydir` because it has more length than `foo/bar/dir2` .
To avoid this we can get `heapq` but it will be an overkill. An additional if clause can be used to check if the `inner list` has `len` >2

Comment: That's great! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I guess that when the list of more complicated I should just call that operation recursively

Comment: `[os.makedirs(max(elem)) for elem in d]` u can do this ..your dirs will be created